# Regression coefficient as weights

Tags: multiple-regression, weighted-regression

I am not good enough in Statistics. I have a data in which there are four variables and one response variable. Is there any way so I can use my regression coefficients as weights?

I have one condition on sum of weights should be 1. I want something which works as weights

```
SCORE = B1*X1 +B2*X2 + B3*X3 + B4*X4
```

and sum of all Betas is equals to 1.

Any statistical technique can be acceptable.

Comment: So, you don't mind if some of the coefficients are negative?

Comment: If you really want your betas to sum to 1, then you have $\beta_4 = 1-(\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3)$. Plugging it into your formula, you will see that you have a usual unconstrained regression with three predictors (instead of four). However, I suspect that you mean something else.

Comment: My Beta's will work as percentage of contribution it should be in 0 and 1 suggest any answer even if it gives negative beta

Comment: If any technique is acceptable, then score $= (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4)/4$ qualifies. That's a serious answer but leaves wide open whether there is a better answer for your purposes. A slightly deeper point is that your purposes here are not defined.

Comment: It means it will assign 25% weight to each variable. It can be one possibility of answer. But that weights may or may not be same for each variables  it depends on variables.

Comment: OK, but as you haven't said what's "good" for you, the question admits only a perfect circle: "any weights that sum to 1" is the solution. The answer from @Tommy L says the same thing: what criterion do you want to minimise?

Comment: I have a data in which response lies between 1 to 25 and same as variables. I want response should be like weighted average or any linear combination which satisfy that condition in order to obtain maximum accuracy. Basic condition is sum of coefficients should be 1.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think we're getting closer here. You have one full answer you've not commented on. The expectation is that you accept it or say why it misunderstands the question or is not the answer you seek.

Answer (score 5):

You must specify what criterion you want to minimise. You talk about regression, so assuming you mean ordinary linear regression, your optimisation problem would be
$$
    \text{minimise}\; \frac12\|y-X\beta\|_2^2
$$
$$
    \text{subject to}\; \|\beta\|_2 = 1.
$$

If you relax this problem slightly (in fact, the KKT conditions state that your solution is found when $\|\beta\|_2=1$), you obtain a convex problem that can be solved very easily with a simple gradient procedure: State the problem as
$$
    \text{minimise}\; \frac12\|y-X\beta\|_2^2
$$
$$
    \text{subject to}\; \|\beta\|_2 \leq 1,
$$
then iterate on
$$
    \beta^{k+1} = \rho(\beta^k - t X^T(X\beta^k - y)),
$$
where
$$
    \rho(x)=\begin{cases}
             x & \text{if}\; \|x\|_2 \leq 1 \\
             \frac{x}{\|x\|_2} & \text{otherwise}
         \end{cases}
$$
is the projection onto the $\ell_2$ norm ball and $t$ is a step size.

This method is called projected gradient descent.